# How to check "is set" and "is empty"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm transitioning from PHP to Python. In PHP isset() and empty() can easily help you determine if an array key (dictionary key in Python) is set or if it is empty (falsey).

Is there a simple way to see if a dictionary key is set or empty in Python 3? I've noticed some solutions that point you to various try/except catches.

PHP isset() function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

> Determine if a variable is considered set, this means if a variable is declared and is different than NULL.

PHP empty() function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.

Comment: Do you want to check if there is an entry for some key in the dictionary? Then use `.get(<key>)`. It will return `None` if not present

Comment: Perhaps those conditions: `'test_key' in test_dict` and `test_dict['test_key'] is None`

Comment: There are easy common idioms for both use cases which do not involve `try`/`except`. Many times, an exception is going to be more efficient (the `try` will succeed and so you save cycles by not looking before you leap) but both styles are common and reasonably Pythonic. Look for `hasattr` and simple equality comparison. I don't know PHP but I guess `isset` corresponds to multiple cases in Python (undefined vs None).

Comment: It is very rare to write Python code that depends whether a *variable* exists or not. Checking whether a dictionary contains a value for a specific key is a completely different thing.

Comment: I just edited the question for clarity. Let's assume the dictionary case, as that's the one I seem to be running into the most.

Comment: @molbdnilo, it may be rare, but I have a valid use case. A model class and a mixin that both need to initialize or add to a list property. Without knowing which one is executed first, each case would need to see if that list var already exists. So "rare" doesn't mean it isn't needed in a language.

Comment: @ExTexan It's never needed (and is impossible) in sensible languages; you use a variable that always exists and whose initial value is "nothing"; `None` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can test is a key is present in a dictionary with `in`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
>>> 'a' in d
True
>>> 'x' in d
False
```

You can also try to find a value and get a default (by default `None`) if the key is not present with get:

```
>>> d.get('a')
'b'
>>> d.get('x')
>>> d.get('x') is None
True
>>> d.get('x', 'y')      # 'y' is the default value here
'y'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `d = {'x':None}; d.get('x') is None` --> `True`

Comment: @Drako Well, it is *by design*... Set to a False value or even to None is still set in the dictionary. If you do not want `None` then test for that: `d.get('a') is not None`.